# How could store multiple files with carrierwave on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

How to upload 2 different files  in a form with carrierwave.
At first  I create two different uploader to hold the 2 files.

```
> app/uploaders/cdf_uploader.rb
> app/uploaders/msword_uploader.rb
```

but when I upload the 2 files , it will auto put the files in 2 different folder.

```
public/uploads/CONTOLLER/cdf_file
public/uploads/CONTOLLER/msword_file
```

but how could I store the 2 files in one folder.
but keep  my table structure unchange.

http://d.pr/i/7nDu

you can check the form view snapshot here http://d.pr/i/EQWE

Thanks ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `store_dir` and rest all will look good then so in  your uploaders just defined a common `store_dir`

something like this

```
def store_dir
  "public/uploads/storage/#{model.id}"
end
```

### NOTE

If the file are of same name and extension you might find odd behavior one overwriting and other and causing problem in carrierwave just and assumption though :)